# Make a function async/threaded in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an interesting question for you. I have a function in Android that interacts with the ui by loading a listview with data from a remote server. As expected, this makes my app extremely sluggish.

With the minimum amount of code, how do I put this function on its own thread or A Sync Task, while still allowing it to perform like a normal function

It did not be extremely efficient. I just need to do this with the minimum amount of code possible.

```
try
    {   //getjson file
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
    HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  

        if (resEntityGet != null) {
            InputStream instream = resEntityGet.getContent();
            BufferedReader str = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    instream));

            String ans = new String("");
            build = new String("");
            while ((ans = str.readLine()) != null) {
                build = build + ans;
            }
        //parse json file   
            JSONObject total = new JSONObject(build);
            JSONArray prices = null;
            if (!total.isNull("title")){
            Prices = title.getJSONArray("title"));}
            ArrayList<data> newArray = new ArrayList<data>();

            for(int i=0;i<Prices.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject price = null;
                price = Prices.getJSONObject(i);
                data name = new data (price.getString("StoreName"),price.getString("price"),price.getString("Link"));
                newArray.add(name);
            }
            stockArr = new data[newArray.size()];
            stockArr = newArray.toArray(stockArr);
                    //add to listview
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
            listadapter adapter = new listadapter(this,R.layout.listview_item_row, stockArr);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), 10).show();
    }
```

Comment: "With the minimum amount of code" -- SO is not the place to play `Code Golf`, imnsho

Comment: post your code. Ideally, you should hit the remote server, fetch the data, parse it in background and update the adapter in onPostExecute. Additionally, you can use onProgressUpdate if you want intermediate updates, helpful when parsing huge responses

Comment: which of the things of what u just said is skippable?

Comment: Added the code. Also, I understand that an Async task is the best method to update my listview. But right now, I am looking for a quick and easy way to just change my function to async. Any help? :)

Comment: To further clarify, I just want my block of code to run on a thread different from the UI thread, but still have access to UI components.

Comment: You can't turn a function in a simple way to async - once code runs async, you don't know when it is executed. If you could just say "these 5 lines async pls" how would you make sure that the result they produce could be used on the next line? And you can't access the UI when not in the UI thread.

Comment: I am not making any changes to the UI from my main thread. My only object in trying this to prevent the "app not responsive" popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your code for fetching the JSONObject from remote server in the doInBackground() method of AsyncTask class and return that JSONobject from that function. It will get in the onPostExecute() method and there you can parse and load that in to a list view.

```
private class myasyncclass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>{
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Enter code for fetching value from remote server
        return yourjsonobj;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {   
        //Enter code for parsing and create list view
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I pass the context to listadapter in onPostExecute()? getApplicationContext() does not seem to work. Also, will onPostExecute() tie up the UI thread?

Comment: You can set your list adapter object in the main class(out side Asynctask class). You will get that object in the onPostExecute().  private Listadapter yourAdapter;

Comment: I got everything working except this single line. Can you please help? listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: I am receiving an unknown java exception at the point I am setting the adapter to the listview. Everything else is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

**-** Its always a good practice to do the **UI work in a UI thread**, and a **Non-UI work on the Non-UI thread**, but it became a **law** by the arrival of `HoneyComb` version of android.

**-** When an Android application starts it on the **Dedicated UI thread**.

**-** Doing the process expensive tasks like IO, Network calls etc on the UI thread will leave it un-responsive.

**-** So its better to do the Networking calls on the Non-UI thread, that can be done in 2 ways. `Thread` with `Handler` or what we call as **Pain-Less threading** and thats `AsyncTask`.

**See this link:**

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html